# Database Notification

Tags: laravel

I'm able to save my notifications in my database table

```
User::find(138647)->notify(new NotifyDashboard);// this one works!
```

problem is...

it's not saving any notifications in this collection just like in the video
https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3/episodes/10 @5:09

```
>>> Auth::user()->notifications
=> Illuminate\Notifications\DatabaseNotificationCollection {#3296
     all: [],
   }
>>>
```

any help on this one?

Update

discovered something...

in my table if I change the notifiable_type to App\User it shows my notifications counts it too. how can I change it so it shows/counts
App\Models\User instead? these are pictures if it helps [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CM0NG.jpg)  [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbF0Q.jpg)

Another Update...

Somehow, App\User is being saved in DatabaseNotificationCollection when I look at it in Tinker.[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0O2U.jpg) but my App\Models\User isn't. any ideas

Another Update...

the notifications that I'm making somehow isn't creating a new database notification collection instance. so the newCollection function in the DatabaseNotification Class array isn't filling up.

Comment: did you placed use Notifiable; in you user model ?

Comment: yes, there is a Notifiable there.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the `notifiable_type` to change from `App\User` to `App\Models\User` you'd have to create a `Relation::morphMap` like this within your `AppServiceProvider` as especified on the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations):

```
Relation::morphMap([
 'user' => 'App\Models\User',
]);
```

Do remember to `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;` on the Provider.

Comment: so something like this? `class Notification extends Model
{
    use Notifiable;
    //
    public $primaryKey= 'id';
    public $table = 'notifications';
    public $timestamps = false;
    Relation::morphMap([
        'user' => 'App\Models\User',
       ]);
}`

Comment: I was mistaken on my guidance. I've updated my answer now with proper documentation. It should help you out correctly.

Comment: I've tried it. it didn't work for me. ive just updated my question as well. do you mind looking at it?

Comment: @JaimeRojas Maybe to try with plural as in docs: `'users' => 'App\Models\User',`?

Comment: do you use both App/User and App/Models/User actively?

Comment: `'users' => 'App\Models\User'` counts/shows 5 App\User. `'users' => 'App\User'` counts/shows nothing. `'user' => 'App\User'` counts the user that was made with `'user' => 'App\Models\User'` and `'user' => 'App\Models\User'`  counts/shows 5.

Comment: and I just use App\Models\User only

Comment: sorry @JaimeRojas. it did kind of work... but it's counting a different thing